# Download batch files from a website using linux

Tags: linux, batch-file, download

i want to downloads some files (nearly about 1000-2000 zip files) from a website.
i can sit around and add each file one after another. please give me a program or script or whatever method so i can automate the download.

The website i am talking about has download link as

> sitename.com/sometetx/date/12345/folder/12345_zip.zip

date can be taken care of. the main concern is that number 12345 before and after the folder, they both change simultaneously. e.g.

> sitename.com/sometetx/date/23456/folder/23456_zip.zip
>   sitename.com/sometetx/date/54321/folder/54321_zip.zip

i tried using curl

> sitename.com/sometetx/date/[12345-54321]/folder/[12345-54321]_zip.zip

but it makes to much of combination of downloads i.e. keeps left 12345 as it is and scan through 12345 to 54321 the increment left 12345 +1 then repeats scan from [12345-54321].

also tried bash wget 
here i have one variable at two places, when using loop the right 12345 with a " _" is ignored by the program. 
PLease help me, i dont know much about linux or programing, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your loop variable next to `_` to not be ignored by the shell, put it in the quotes, like this:

```
$ for ((i=10000; i < 99999; i++)); do \ 
    wget sitename.com/sometetx/date/$i/folder/"$i"_zip.zip; done
```

Comment: where can i set the output directory , and what default output directory

Comment: Use the `-O` switch, like: `for ((i=10000; i < 99999; i++)); do wget -O $i.zip http://sitename.com/sometetx/date/$i/folder/"$i"_zip.zip; done`

Comment: one more thing how can i get them into foler according to their names i.e the vairiable

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: trying to download some files to my pc .